# how can i insert a standlone game project (html js) inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, insert

I want to render a standlone html js project (game project) inside a react component.

[standlone html js project portion code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPZXU.png)

**react component**

```
export default function Tetris() {
  function iframe() {
    return {
      __html:
        '<iframe src="../../../Standlone Games/Tetris/index.html" width="540" height="450"></iframe>',
    };
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={iframe()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UJ0W.png)

I have tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML & iframe , but i receive a 404 (Not Found) error and an empty frame !
while the path is 100% correct!

[result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UJ0W.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not render a native `<iframe>` element in the component?

```js
const { useState } = React;

const GAME_URL = "https://ceolter.github.io/tetris/";

const Tetris = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Tetris">
      <iframe
        src={GAME_URL}
        width={540}
        height={450}>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Tetris</h1>
      <Tetris />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App title="Example using Hooks:" />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution with my local path  :  `const GAME_URL = "../../../Standlone Games/Tetris/index.html";
export default function Tetris() {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe src={GAME_URL} width={540} height={450}></iframe>
    </div>
  );`                                                                                                                                        
But i receive always  `GET http://localhost:5173/Standlone%20Games/Tetris/index.html 404 (Not Found)` .  Maybe because the paths is local  (in my case), and i don't want to deploy the game project !

Answer (score 2):

Thans to Mr. Polywhirl's idea , i just replaced the path to the absolute path and it works fine!
Solution:

```
const GAME_URL = "/src/Standlone Games/Tetris/index.html";

export default function Tetris() {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe src={GAME_URL} width={540} height={600}></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```